# CheckStyle Eclipse Plugin don't display the labels correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

i am using `checkStyle eclipse plugin` ,but the labels of the plugin are not displayed correctly, 
i am using the current  version `5.7.0.201402131929` [image: preferences->CheckStyle]

So i wonder if there is any suggestions ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am using same version and labels are correctly displayed. I would suggest you to unstall all checkstyle plugin from eclipse from

```
Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Installed Software .
```

Select all checkstyle related softwares and uninstall them.

Then install Checkstyle plugin again from

```
Help > Eclipse Market Place
```

Issue should resolved.

**NOTE:-**  [steps](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) may vary depending upon eclipse version

Comment: whats the eclipse version ?

Comment: i am using eclipse Juno 4